# Unable to load Complex JSON Spark HQL - _corrupt_record error

Tags: json, apache-spark, hql, apache-spark-sql

I tried to load the below JSON file in Spark HQL, but could not be loaded successfully. Gives _corrupt_record error.

Can anyone shed some light on this error? I can read and use the file with other applications like Notepad++(JSTool plugin) and I am confident it is proper and not corrupt.

```html
{"markers": [
  {
   "point":new GLatLng(40.266044,-74.718479), 
   "homeTeam":"Lawrence Library",
   "awayTeam":"LUGip",
   "markerImage":"images/red.png",
   "information": "Linux users group meets second Wednesday of each month.",
   "fixture":"Wednesday 7pm",
   "capacity":"",
   "previousScore":""
  },
  {
   "point":new GLatLng(40.211600,-74.695702),
   "homeTeam":"Hamilton Library",
   "awayTeam":"LUGip HW SIG",
   "markerImage":"images/white.png",
   "information": "Linux users can meet the first Tuesday of the month to work out harward and configuration issues.",
   "fixture":"Tuesday 7pm",
   "capacity":"",
   "tv":""
  },
  {
   "point":new GLatLng(40.294535,-74.682012),
   "homeTeam":"Applebees",
   "awayTeam":"After LUPip Mtg Spot",
   "markerImage":"images/newcastle.png",
   "information": "Some of us go there after the main LUGip meeting, drink brews, and talk.",
   "fixture":"Wednesday whenever",
   "capacity":"2 to 4 pints",
   "tv":""
  },
] }
```

Comment: please share your attempted code

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON should be in one line per one object

```
{ object1 }
{ object2 }
```

Only this structure is supported by default `read.json`. If you want to read multi-line JSONs, it would be possible via `sparkContext.wholeTextFiles` and manual parsing

In documentation is [text](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets):

> Note that the file that is offered as a json file is not a typical
>   JSON file. Each line must contain a separate, self-contained valid
>   JSON object. As a consequence, a regular multi-line JSON file will
>   most often fail.